# Joomla DB Insert, how to get last inserted id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert my data into 2 different tables, in the first table I have the following query which works perfectly:

```
$insertProjectUser = 'INSERT INTO #__pmanager_user (user_cms_id, user_email, user_created_ip) VALUES (' . $user->id . ', "' . $user->email . '", "' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '")';
$db->setQuery($insertProjectUser );
$db->query();
```

This table has an auto-incremented column called `project_user_id` and I need this value immediately.

How can I correctly get the "last inserted id"? I tried more solutions like:

- mysqli_insert_id($db)
- $selectedID = insertid()
- mysqli_insert_id($db)

All these solutions provide only zero 0 value.

---

Updated:

My query is:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$insertProjectUser = 'INSERT INTO #__pmanager_user (user_cms_id, user_email, user_created_ip) VALUES (' . $user->id . ', "' . $user->email . '", "' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '")';
$db->setQuery($insertProjectUser );
$db->query();
$addressID = $db->insertid();
```

If I do: `echo $addressID`, I get nothing (empty string).

Comment: Is it possible that your table lacks an "id" field with autoincrement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is not related to Joomla. Just Google around for your problem. The fist answer I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0):

> The problem seemed to be in MySQL's phpmyadmin config file
>   PersistentConnections set to FALSE which resulted in a new
>   CONNECTION_ID every time a query was issued - therefore rendering
>   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() ineffective.

Answer (score 7):

To get the ID of the last inserted row, you can use `insertid()` like so:

```
$db->query();
$lastRowId = $db->insertid();
```

You can then use `$lastRowId` where ever you wish in your next query

Update with latest DB coding standards (J2.5)

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('user_cms_id', 'user_email', 'user_created_ip');   
$values = array($db->quote($user->id), $db->quote($user->email), $db->quote($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__pmanager_user'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
      ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();

$addressID = $db->insertid();

echo $addressID;
```

Comment: This return also 0, i tried again but the same problem...

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? Cause I've just tested this and it works perfectly fine for me

Comment: Joomla 2.5.16, php: 5.5.9, everytime i get 0 as value.

Comment: I'm not going to try replicating this on Joomla 2.5.16. You need to update to Joomla 2.5.28 as you're 12 versions behind in the 2.5 series

Comment: I updated it but there is still the same problem, i controlled also db version is the same like joomla 2.5.28, is this statement correct: $db = JFactory::getDbo(); ?

Comment: Please update your question with two queries that you are using. Or even better provide the whole part of the code to see how these queries are used.

Comment: I updated my question, there is my query.

Comment: @xxx - I never use native mysql in Joomla database queries so I've added an update to my answer. Please trying copying and pasting the code to see if you get the required results

Comment: @Lodder the same result "0", row proporties in db are: http://prntscr.com/5jq138, can mysql version be a problem? My db version is: 5.6.16

Comment: I don't believe the mysql version is an issue as I'm using 5.6.17 which is only 1 minor version ahead of yours.

Comment: Does your first data get inserted? Is the ID really not 0? What is the result if your $db->query()?

Comment: I hope you do realise though that `$db->insertid();` returns the latest ID from the `ID` column (not `user_id`) which should be an auto increment type.

Comment: Data is correct inserted and id is also correct, means not 0. I create now $db_address instead of $db, but there is the same problem, i get still 0 :(

Answer (score 1):

The `insertid` function, in Joomla 3.7.4 (and in many previous Joomla versions), relies on the extremely unreliable `mysqli_insert_id` PHP function. On extremely active sites, this function will mostly return 0 or an inaccurate number. Let me explain a bit:

- If the last activity on the database is an `insert` or an `update` activity and the table structure has an autoincrement column, then the value of that column is returned.
- If the last activity on the database is a `select` activity, for example, then the function will return 0.
- If there was another `insert`/`update` subsequent activity after your `insert`, then the function will return the ID of the autoincrement column of the last `insert`/`update`.

The problem with this whole thing is not really Joomla, but MySQL, which doesn't have a reliable method to get the last ID inserted. The most reliable (but still far from ideal) method to get the last inserted ID is to query the table for a unique value. For example, if you are inserting a contact with a unique email, then you will need to query the table for his email.

Hope this helps, and if someone has better information on the subject, then feel free to comment or edit this answer.

Comment: you voiced my suspicions well

Comment: Umm...Shouldn't the last insert ids and things like that, be isolated to their respective connection in mysql out of the box? Thats what the "I" in ACID Compliance stands for. Or am I missing something?