# How to get the generated id after a successful INSERT query?

Tags: joomla-3.4, mysql, jdatabase, jtable

I would like to get the `id` of the last saved dataset in a JTable-Operation.

At the moment I got this:

```
// Create and populate an object.
$value         = new stdClass();
$value->userid = (int)$userid;
$value->type   = $data['type']; 

// Insert the object into the user profile table.
$handle = JFactory::getDbo()->insertObject('#__bestia_handles', $value);
```

Now I would like to get the `id` of this saved object.

`$handle` only contains `true` or `false`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it :-)

Just define

```
$db                         =   JFactory::getDbo();
```

and after

```
$db->insertObject(...)
```

I'm able to call

```
$db->insertid();
```

Comment: Please note this may not always work: See this:http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5768/168

Comment: Thanks a lot - as far as I understood the reason for this behavior is not clear yet?
In my case it works fine - but of course I would like to use a method that always works ;-)

Comment: This problem is caused by bad MySQL configuration. You will not meet it on most of the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as I'm using multiple tables for my data and linking them however this seems like a good method, although one thing I don't understand though is there a reason why JTable's save method only returns true/false surely it would be better to return item id or NULL as that would be so much more useful.  Of course I presume there is nothing to stop you creating an override in your own table class to do so like this...

```
    MyComponentTableMyTable extends JTable
    {
        public function save($src, $orderingFilter= '', $ignore= '')
        {
            /*call parent save function and return either insertid or null depending on whether or not parent save function returns true or false */
            return ( parent::save ( $src, $orderingFilter, $ignore ) ? $_db->insertid () : NULL ) ;
        }
    }
```

I haven't actually tried this yet but can't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a single row of data, try using *JTable*. It follows the Active Record pattern. After performing a `$row->save()`, `$row->id` is updated with the actual value of the primary key.