# Get ID for new Article or Category

Tags: articles, category, id, itemid

I'm programming in a button to allow users to add a new category or article but I'm also tracking the IDs to create the custom webpage structure.

So when the user clicks the button I need to know the ID that was just created. I haven't found the documentation that says how to capture that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I could look up the last ID created but if multiple users are creating articles or categories at the same time that method probably is not going to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joomla DB Insert, how to get last inserted id?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/joomla-db-insert-how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relevant discussion here, but in short it just concludes that using the jdatabase insertid method is just as rubbish as mysqli_insert_id.

[Joomla DB Insert, how to get last inserted id?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/joomla-db-insert-how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

The trick is to do a select using fields that you already have from the insert query, eg. get max id & match the userid, or any other fields that you might have, and include the selected id in the response.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for a more streamlined method but I'll have to stick with what you suggest.